# at() function to a new variable

Tags: c++

I would like to put each char of a string into a new string variable. How can I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string str = "Hello";

    string A = str.at(0);

    string B = str.at(1);

    string C = str.at(2);

    string D = str.at(3);

    string E = str.at(4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat strings as containers, so you may use the following code:

```
char A = str[0];
char B = str[1];
```

And if you'd like to convert the character into a string, use the following code:

```
string A(1, str[0]);
string B(1, str[1]);
```

Comment: Using `at()` for `std::string` is better than using `operator[]` since the former performs bounds check, while the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This will compile :
char A = str.at(0);

[std::string::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/)